# Apex5.0 choose layout and add date validation

Tags: oracle-apex

I am building a student module application in Oracle Apex 5.0 and wanted to know how to display the details in oracle apex.

Something like this with two tabs on the 1 page:

on first tab, When input StudentID,

> the first section will contain system_date and tutor name that has login 
>   second section should contain student name and course desc & course year
>   third section is to display current semester module, if payment done or not (Y /N), markings %, date of payment.

2nd tab of the page to include all courses done for that student.

Which layout to choose (interactive grid/report) or any other.
How to add validation of date picker for the payment date so that upon input it insert directly in table in DD-MON-YY format and also that it takes system_date??

Note table:

- `student_details`: the student name, address and personal details
- `course_detail` table contains the courses for the semester
  `payment_detail` table for the payment details

Answer (score 0):

The sort of things you're going to want to look for are:

- Region Display selector, for multiple tabs
- Any type of report region to display data, and you can have multiple, and nest them as sub-regions.
- You can define page items that are displayed as date pickers, and use default values to source today's date using the keyword SYSDATE.

You're going to need to understand SQL.